# How to Pass Array from Zend Dom Query Results to table

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-dom-query

I am querying a URL for columns YEAR, RATING and I want to insert those two into a database. E.g.
YEAR RATING
1992 9.2
2000 9
1999 8
. .
. .
. .
. .

So, I am writing script like:

```
$url = 'BLA BLA ';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($data);
$year = $dom->query('.secondaryInfo');
$rating = $dom->query('.ratingColumn');
```

How to insert both of them in a database???

```
for ( .... What do I have to write here?)

$parse = new Application_Model_Parse();
$parse->createImdb(array(
'rating' => What do I have to write here?
'year' => What do I have to write here?
));
```

Any help will be useful.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As explained at http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.dom.query.html

> Once you have a document, you can use either the `query()` or `queryXpath()` methods; each method will return a `Zend_Dom_Query_Result` object with any matching nodes.

And further

> As mentioned previously, `Zend_Dom_Query_Result` implements both `Iterator` and `Countable`, and as such can be used in a `foreach()` loop as well as with the `count()` function.

The various [Iterator methods](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) will return [PHP's native DOMElements](http://php.net/DOMElement) in this case, which means you can access the Element's text content via it's `nodeValue` property.

Assuming there is only one item in the Result object, try

```
$parse->createImdb(
    array(
        'rating' => $rating->current()->nodeValue
        'year' => $year->current()->nodeValue
    )
);
```

If you feel uncomfortable working with an Iterator, you can use:

- [`iterator_to_array` — Copy the iterator into an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php)

to, well, copy the iterator into an array and then use that instead, e.g.

```
$rating = iterator_to_array($rating);
$year = iterator_to_array($year);
$parse->createImdb(
    array(
        'rating' => $rating[0]->nodeValue
        'year' => $year[0]->nodeValue
    )
);
```

If there is multiple results, iterate them together with a [MultipleIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/multipleiterator.construct.php)

```
$ratingsAndYears = new MultipleIterator();
$ratingsAndYears->attachIterator($rating);
$ratingsAndYears->attachIterator($year);

foreach ($ratingsAndYears as $ratingAndYear) {
    $parse = new Application_Model_Parse();
    $parse->createImdb(
        array(
            'rating' => $ratingAndYear[0]->nodeValue
            'year' => $ratingAndYear[1]->nodeValue
        )
    );
```

On a sidenote, `Zend_Dom_Query` is just a thin wrapper around PHP's native DOM extension and if you know [XPath](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html), you don't really need the W3 Selector querying it offers and can do it all with DOM alone.